# Lifting a computation from the State monad into the RWS monad

Tags: haskell, state, monads, writer, reader

I structure a computation around the use of the `RWS` (`Reader`+`Writer`+`State`) monad:

```
newtype Problem a = Problem { unProblem :: RWS MyEnv MyLog MyState a }
                    deriving ({- lots of typeclasses -})
```

The computation is built step by step by assembling elementary computations of the form

```
foo :: a -> Problem b
```

Sometimes, however, the subcomputations do not need the full power of the `RWS` monad. For instance, consider

```
bar :: c -> State MyState d
```

I would like to use `bar` as a part of a larger computation in the context of the `Problem` monad. I can see three ways of doing this, none of which seems very elegant to me.

1. Manually unwrap the  the `State` computation and rewrap it in the RWS monad:

   ```
   baz :: a -> RWS MyEnv MyLog MyState c
   baz x = do temp <- foo x
              initialState <- get
              let (finalResult, finalState) = runState (bar temp) initialState
              put finalState
              return finalResult
   ```
2. Modify the type signature of `bar` by lifting it into the `Problem` monad. This has the downside that the new type signature does not explicitly promise that `bar` is independent of `MyEnv` and logs nothing to `MyLog`.
3. Replace the `RWS` monad by an explicit `ReaderT MyEnv WriterT MyLog State MyState` monad stack. This allows me to concisely `lift.lift` the `bar` subcomputation into the full monad; however, this trick will not work e.g. for a subcomputation of the form `c -> Reader MyEnv d`.

Is there a cleaner way to compose `foo` and `bar`? I have a hunch that a few clever definitions of type-class instances might do the trick, but I can't see exactly how to proceed.

Comment: Are you using RWS from the transformers package or from mtl?

Comment: I am using `mtl`. I was actually not aware of `transformers`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are using [`mtl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) (if you aren't, consider doing so - the libraries are mostly compatible, except for what follows). You can derive instances of `MonadReader MyEnv`, `MonadWriter MyLog`, and `MonadState MyState`. Then, you can use these to generalize your functions over *any* monad stack that has these sort of constraints.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad.RWS
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Control.Monad.State

newtype Problem a = Problem { unProblem :: RWS MyEnv MyLog MyState a }
                    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad,
                              MonadReader MyEnv, MonadWriter MyLog, MonadState MyState)
```

From your example, maybe `bar` only needs to know that there is some state `MyState`, so you can give it signature

```
bar :: MonadState MyState m => c -> m d
bar = ...
```

Then, even for `foo`, which might need the full `RWS` capabilities, you could write

```
foo :: (MonadState MyState m, MonadReader MyEnv m, MonadWriter MyLog m) => a -> m b
foo = ...
```

Then, you can mix and match these to your liking:

```
baz :: Problem ()
baz = foo 2 >> bar "hi" >> return ()
```

---

Now, why is this useful in general? It boils down to the flexibility of your monad "stack". If tomorrow you decide that you don't actually need `RWS` but only `State`, you can refactor `Problem` accordingly and `bar` (which only ever needed state in the first place) will continue to work without any changes.

In general, I try to avoid using `WriterT`, `StateT`, `RWST` etc inside auxiliary functions like `foo` or `bar`. Opt to keep your code there as generic and implementation-independent as possible using the typeclasses `MonadWriter`, `MonadState`, `MonadReader`, etc. Then, you only have to use `WriterT`, `StateT`, `RWST` once inside your code: when you actually "run" your monad.

#### Side note about `transformers`

If you are using [`transformers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers), none of this works. That isn't necessarily a bad thing: `mtl`, by virtue of always being able to "find" components (like state or writer) [has some problems](https://ro-che.info/articles/2014-06-11-problem-with-mtl).

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. The link at the end is very relevant.

Comment: That last link was super interesting. I was under the (perhaps naive) impression that Monad stacks only made code _easier_ to reuse across different applications.

Comment: @Undreren You might also be interested in the sequels to that article: [1](https://ro-che.info/articles/2014-06-14-extensible-effects-failed), [2](https://ro-che.info/articles/2014-07-15-type-based-lift), [3](https://ro-che.info/articles/2014-06-14-extensible-effects-failed). That said, I haven't ever myself run into the limitations of `mtl` in a real-life situation.